# Pandas installation stuck at Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: python, pandas, raspberry-pi

I've been facing with problems while trying to deploy a Python application to a Raspberry Pi 2 (GLIBC 2.28-10+rpi1). My application is deployed in Python 3.9.2, which is the version I installed in the Raspberry.

However, I've been not able to install environment utilities such as Miniconda, which would be useful for packages installation due to deprecated Python version; latest Miniconda available for Raspberry Pi 2 uses Python<3.9.

So I tried to install manually all required packages and I had some troubles with opencv and numpy; the first I managed to install with `apt`, whereas numpy could be installed through `pip3`. Now I have to install pandas but it remains stuck while installing through `pip3`. In non-verbose output, it gets stuck in "Getting requirements to build wheel`. In the verbose one, it seems to get stuck when lastly prints "Compiling pandas/io/sas/sas.pyx because it changed".

What can I do? Is a Python 3.9 application impossible to deploy in such an old Raspberry? Thank you all in advance

EDIT: after half an hour stuck in that output line, it got stuck again (for more than an hour currently) in a `gcc` command.

Comment: I would recommend to try upgrading both pip and setuptools.